# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime

Tags: ios, ruby, rvm

This is error when I type `rvm install 2.3.0` in mac's terminal:

[image]

Comment: what's mean? remove ruby first?

Comment: Please remove an image and copy-paste the actual code instead. Also, please read SO rules on how to ask questions.

Comment: the answers on this thread are ridiculous

Answer (score 11):

All you should have to do is install the command line tools by running the following in the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

I'm running Xcode 8 GM Seed.

Comment: This worked for me (Ruby 2.4.0, Xcode 8.2.1, OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan).

Answer (score 1):

I had Xcode 8 installed while still running El Capitan. I removed Xcode 8, and reinstalled Xcode 7.

Perhaps I could have upgraded to Sierra, but that would have been world of different hurt.